# C++ Array Output Issue

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm writing a simple program that needs to take in the number of elements a user wants in their array. The program then needs to read in the elements of the array and display the output. Some rules of the program are:

- The maximum number of integers are to be handled are 20.
- All numbers entered and displayed will be integer values.

For some reason I keep getting the output of the array plus the previous question relayed to the user.

EX:

[image: Output Example]

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
     const int ARRAY_SIZE = 20;
     int inputOne = 0;
     int arrayOne[ARRAY_SIZE];

     cout << "Enter how many numbers you'd like to read in up to 20: ";
     cin >> inputOne; 
     //Input the numbers
     for (int input = 0; input < inputOne; input++)
     {
             cout << "Enter in the numbers: ";
             cin >> arrayOne[input];
     }

     //Display the array
     for (int input = 0; input < inputOne; input++)
             cout << arrayOne[input];
     cout << endl;
     system("pause");
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is the output I get from a sample run: `Enter how many numbers you'd like to read in up to 20: 10
Enter in the numbers: 1
Enter in the numbers: 2
Enter in the numbers: 3
Enter in the numbers: 4
Enter in the numbers: 5
Enter in the numbers: 6
Enter in the numbers: 7
Enter in the numbers: 8
Enter in the numbers: 9
Enter in the numbers: 10
12345678910
sh: pause: command not found`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This output is correct. When you use cin for an integer, it waits for an integer, and once it gets one the loop continues. Hence when you type 1 2 3 4 5 you're feeding multiple entries into the loop at a time, and each time the loop is continuing because the next integer is already there.
You might solve this by adjusting your input:

```
Enter in the numbers: 1 [RETURN]
Enter in the numbers: 2 [RETURN]
Enter in the numbers: 3 [RETURN]
Enter in the numbers: 4 [RETURN]
Enter in the numbers: 5 [RETURN]
```

Comment: I took the "Enter in the numbers: " out of the loop and it solved my issue. I don't know why I didn't think of that before.

Answer (score 0):

cin read from the stream, up to the whitespace. with your input your are filling the stream.
when you `1 2 3 4 5 <hit return>` cin reads `1` and stops, the while loop goes for another cin call but only the `1` has been consumed so cin finds the `2` and consume it. and so on.

this bein clarified, you don't have a real problem to fix.

If you want the numbers to be entered like you did in your example just while `cin >> arrayOne[i++]`.

If you want to be asked for every number, just clear the stream after you read the first number with `cin.ignore()` to be sure input as yours only takes the first number.

Answer (score -1):

I was astonished to see the output of your program.
The Problem is only when you are entering the number.
if you press enter instead of space then your code will produce expected result.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/st0SF.png)